# On mp.start(); do setImageResource How?

Tags: android, button, audio, syntax

In the first OnCreate I have a button_stop SetImageResource which changes the icon to a muted icon when pressed, although in my code as a whole I would like to enter a function that says when mp.start(); do another SetImageResource to make the same button show a speaker rather than a muted icon.

How do I make it so that on mp.start(); this function is called?

```
button_stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_on);
```

What I want to do is when a sound button (button_1, button_2) are pressed, button_stop shows a speaker icon. However when button_stop is pressed, it shows a muted icon (and releases the MediaPlayer).

I am able to make it release the MediaPlayer and change the image to a muted icon when the button_stop is pressed, however I'm unable to make it show a speaker icon after opening the MediaPlayer after pressing the sound buttons (button_1 etc)

This is my current code so far. I've tried entering the SetImageResource inside the onClick, but it then stops calling the MediaPlayer correctly.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * @author Prabu
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        final ImageView button_stop=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(null!=mp){
                    mp.release();
                    button_stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_muted);
                     }
            }});
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resId;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            resId = R.raw.a;
            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            resId = R.raw.b;
            break;
        default:
            resId = R.raw.a;
            break;
        }
        // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
        }
        // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();

    }{


                        }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(null!=mp){
            mp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }}
```

Comment: What is your problem? here

Comment: In the current selection of code I haven't entered the function that sets the ImageResource to a spesker icon as I cannot place it anywhere that works. I'm wondering if someone can point in the code as to where it should go so that it works. In the first OnCreate I have a button_stop SetImageResource which changes the icon to a muted icon when pressed, although in my code as a whole I would like to enter a function that says when mp.start(); do another SetImageResource to make the same button show a speaker rather than a muted icon.

Comment: put this explanation into your question.plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my understanding of what you want is simply for the speaker image to turn on when mp.start() is called.  I only see one instance in your code of mp.start(), so this will change the image on the stop button when that happens.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int resId;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_1:
        resId = R.raw.a;
        break;
    case R.id.button_2:
        resId = R.raw.b;
        break;
    default:
        resId = R.raw.a;
        break;
    }
    // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
    }
    // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();

    //This is the added code to set the stop button.
    ImageView button_stop=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
    button_stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_on);

}
```

Comment: That is perfect, exactly what I was looking for! I had tried myself although after looking at your code the reason why I was failing was because I wasn't entering **ImageView button_stop=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);** I thought as it was already stated earlier I didn't have to do it again.

Comment: If you put it in a global variable you don't have to "find" it again here.  But findViewById is fast...especially if you're searching the direct parent view.  Its just searching a list of integers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setBackgroundResource(R.id.img)` instead of `setImageResource(R.id.image)` will solve the problem. Replace this part of your code:

```
button_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(null!=mp){
                mp.release();
                button_stop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_muted);
                 }
        }});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: setting the image resource already calls invalidate() internally.

Comment: I have edit my answer with `setBackgroundResource()` @user3126670